# SpringBoot: Is possible deploy my views on https and rest services on 8080 port?

Tags: rest, spring-boot, deployment, frontend, port

I am starting with spring boot, amd I have a project with jsp views and rest services. All in the same project. Then, when I wanted to deploy, the clients say me that the views, must be in https://example.com, and my web services on example.com:8080... Now, I have the project with the views and rest services in the same place and running on 8080 port.. is possible deploy only my views for https and my rest services for 8080 port? Or I need separate and build two .war files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTTP vs HTTPS choice is a matter of server configuration. You could deploy your views in a server with HTTPS and your REST services in a server without HTTPS.

However, I cannot see the reason to do that because the communication between your views (executed in a web browser) and the services (server) will not be secure.

So why have the views inside HTTPS? Some browsers will complain and warn the user when you try to access a non secure resource from a secure context.

Comment: Yes, I think the same. In the beginning, I thought that, that server (8080 port) could be accessible only in the internal network, but I it does not, that server is accessible from the web... It's very strange... then, the URLs of the views, can be configured to be served by https?

Comment: The bottom line is that, when the user accesses your views, the server sends the generated HTML to her. Any interaction with services is initiated by the user web browser. If your services are not in a secure context, you'll have security issues. A possible approach is to have a secure web server (e.g.: Nginx) just tunneling the requests to a non-secure Java Web container (e.g.: Tomcat). This way you'll have everything secured. See, for example this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-encrypt-tomcat-8-connections-with-apache-or-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: If you consider that the answer is correct, do not forget to vote it up.